# Error in Unit testing with Angular js 1.6.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Hi I am doing basic unit testing with Angularjs 1.5.6 and getting error.
        Using karma and Jasmine for unit testing.
        Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
        I have tried many hit and trail but no luck.
        is there any easy way to do this.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) Name of group should return movie list FAILED
        TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$http.get(url)
                        .success') in src/omdb/service.js (line 9)
        httpPromise@src/omdb/service.js:9:25
        search@src/omdb/service.js:20:23
        spec/omdb/service.spec.js:17:23
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:162:17
```

My service.js is

```
angular.module('omdb', [])
.factory('omdbApi', function ($http, $q) {
    var service = {};
    var baseUrl = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?v=1&';

    function httpPromise(url){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(url)
            .success(function (data) {
                //return response.data;
                return deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(){
                deferred.reject();
            })
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    service.search = function (query) {
       httpPromise(baseUrl+'s='+encodeURIComponent(query))
    }
    service.find = function (id) {
        httpPromise(baseUrl+'i='+id)
    }
    return service;
})
```

Comment: If you need spec.js code please let me know

Comment: `.success()` is simply not there in Angular 1.6. Have you not updated your tests?